# Tracing recursion for fibonacci series

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to understand the recursion mechanism used for fibonacci series.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fib(int n);
int main()
{
    int x, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    x = fib(n);
    printf("fibonacci number %d = %d\n", n, x);
    return 0;
}
int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (fib(n -1) + fib(n - 2));
    }
}
```

Above is the code for the series. I can trace the program(for n=6) till the point where the first term in the return calls fib(1) and then returns 1. After that, I am kinda lost in tracing the execution. I have tried to understand it through stack diagrams but I am still confused. Can anybody help me with this? Also how  can I trace the stack frame using gdb and see the variable values on stack frames?

Thanks

Comment: It works off the systematic approach where f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2). Given two base cases to start with: f(0) and f(1), you can calculate the nth Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `fib(4)`, you get the following chain of calls:

```
fib(4) = fib(3)                             + fib(2)
         = fib(2)             + fib(1)        = fib(1) + fib(0)
           = fib(1) + fib(0)    = 1             = 1      = 0
             = 1      = 0
```

A good way to see that would be the following modification to your function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fib(int n, int m);
int main()
{
    int x, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    x = fib(n, n);
    printf("fibonacci number %d = %d\n", n, x);
    return 0;
}
int fib(int n, int m)
{
    printf("calling fib(%d) from fib(%d)\n", n, m);
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (fib(n -1, n) + fib(n - 2, n));
    }
}
```

Which results in

```
calling fib(4) from fib(4)
calling fib(3) from fib(4)
calling fib(2) from fib(3)
calling fib(1) from fib(2)
calling fib(0) from fib(2)
calling fib(1) from fib(3)
calling fib(2) from fib(4)
calling fib(1) from fib(2)
calling fib(0) from fib(2)
fibonacci number 4 = 3
```

There's your "stack trace" in a nutshell...

Comment: Should't it `fib(0) = 0` ?

Comment: @haccks you are right - my bad. Good eye.

Comment: By the way Fibonacci series begins with `0`(AFAIK): `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13,....` :)

Comment: No. I don't have problem. It looks fine to me. I just informed you about the series.

Answer (score 8):

To understand this, I renamed your `fib` fnction to `fibonacci`. Now suppose user enters `3` then the recursive call can be understand as (`>` is for call and `<` is for return):

```
> fibonacci(3)
|   > fibonacci(2)
|   |   > fibonacci(1)
|   |   < 1
|   |   > fibonacci(0)
|   |   < 0
|   < 1
|   > fibonacci(1)
|   < 1
< 2
```

Which can be understand more in a more clear way by block diagram<sup>1</sup>.

[image]

---

<sub>1. Taken from [C how to program by Deitel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0273776843).</sub>

Comment: Nice diagram, very clear

Comment: @haccks, could you post where you got that diagram from? Is there a "template" that you can use for other recursive tracing? I was trying to answer this question by just typing out my own block diagram but it was a big pain.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma; The same thing happens when I was trying to answer similar question few hours ago :). I taken this snippet from the book I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @haccks Thanks! I was just finishing my messy answer as you posted. Yours looked much nicer!

Comment: Now this is something different from programming: [Fibonacci Numbers in Nature 
& the Golden Ratio](http://www.world-mysteries.com/sci_17.htm). Mathematics fans would really love this. :)

Answer (score 8):

think of some random number and draw steps of execution(like a tree). i'd always use pen and paper 
to understand algorithm stuff. and also, always try to break down the whole program to each tiny logic and make sure you understand each one of them. I drew this diagram for you.i'm sorry for being such a horrible artist. [image]

Comment: +1 for the diagram. At least you drew it your self. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
else
{
    printf ("n is: %d\n", n);
    printf ("The program will go the %d-1 and %d-2 now.", n, n);
    return (fib(n -1) + fib(n - 2));
}
```

this will show you what number the program is working on each time it works on a new number. This way you can see what the program does.

Comment: The values of n depicted in sequence(for n=5) are 5 4 3 2 2 3 2. Till the first time n==2, I can understand the operation, but I am kinda lost after that one. Could you please explain?

Comment: Yeah, the program will always go to fib(n-1) first, and fib (n-2) next, right? so you entered 5, the program went to 5-1, then 4-1, 3-1, 2-1 and reached to 1. You ordered to return at 1, so it returned to 2 and went to 2-2, reached 0, returned to 3. It will always go to n-1 first, and when it returns, it will go to n-2 part.

Comment: After returning at n=1, it returns to n=2 and calls fib(2-2) i.e fib(0). Then it returns at n=3 and calls fib(3-2) i.e fib(1),and then returns at n=4 and calls fib(2) which in turn calls fib(1) returns and calls and fib(0). Is that correct?

Comment: @VaibhavSundriyal; See the block diagram in my answer.

Comment: @haccks  Thanks a lot. The flow is clear to me now.